# Ramification in subfield lattice of a cyclotomic field

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields, ramification

Fix a positive integer $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$.
Consider the cyclotomic field $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$.

I know that only $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ are ramified in $K/\Bbb Q$, and that the ramification index of $p_i$ is $\varphi(p_i^{a_i})$.

> How do the primes $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ ramify in the subfield lattice of $K/\Bbb Q$?

For example, if $n=20$ then the ramification is
\begin{matrix}
  &&\Bbb Q(\zeta_{20})\\
  &\llap{2}\huge\diagup&\llap{\varnothing}\huge|&\rlap{5}\huge\diagdown\\
  \Bbb Q(\zeta_5)&&\Bbb Q(\zeta_{20}+\zeta_{20}^{-1})&&\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt5)\\
  &\rlap{5}\huge\diagdown&\llap{2,5}\huge|&\llap{2}\huge\diagup&\llap{\varnothing}\huge|&\rlap{5}\huge\diagdown\\
  &&\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)&&\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-5})&&\Bbb Q(i)\\
  &&&\rlap{5}\huge\diagdown&\llap{2,5}\huge|&\llap{2}\huge\diagup\\
  &&&&\Bbb Q
\end{matrix}
I suspect that there might be a way to read this ramification data off from the corresponding subgroup lattice
\begin{matrix}
  &&\{1\}\\
  &\huge\diagup&\huge|&\huge\diagdown\\
  \{1,11\}&&\{1,19\}&&\{1,9\}\\
  &\huge\diagdown & \huge| & \huge\diagup & \huge| & \huge\diagdown\\
  &&\{1,9,11,19\}&&\{1,3,7,9\}&&\{1,9,13,17\}\\
  &&&\huge\diagdown&\huge|&\huge\diagup\\
  &&&&\{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}
\end{matrix}
In this case, the inertia subgroups are $I_2=\{1,11\}$ and $I_5=\{1,9,13,17\}$.

In general the inertia subgroups are $(\Bbb Z/p_i^{a_i}\Bbb Z)^\times\leq(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$.
However, I don't think that knowing the inertia subgroups is enough to know the entire ramification picture.

Comment: Here's one interesting fact: The extension $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)/\Bbb Q(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1})$ is ramified if and only if $n$ is a prime power (or twice a prime power). This is Proposition 2.15 in Washington's Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields.

Comment: Knowing the inertia subgroup of each prime is enough. Then $e(Q/q) = |I(Q/p) \cap Gal(K/F)|$ from which you deduce all the ramification indices. For such an abelian extension we can also look directly at the (Dirichlet) characters $Hom(Gal(K/\Bbb{Q}),\Bbb{C}^*)$ determining the characters of the subgroups and quotients of $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$ thus all the L-functions.

Comment: Oh, amazing! Do you want to write up an answer?